# Как работая в vs code вставлять в сообщения смайлики из telegram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, visual-studio-code, telegram

Как работая в vs code вставлять в отправляемые строке смайлики из telegram? это нужно для телеграмм бота, используя aiogram

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для отправки emoji вы можете использовать встроенную функцию библиотеки по преобразованию текста в смайлики:

```py
from aiogram.utils.emoji import emojize

emojize(":smile:")
```

[Пример использования](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/proxy_and_emojize.html).

Также можете вставить unicode смайлики в ваш текст, они преобразуются в смайлики в Телеграме. Это может быть как преобзования юникод символа самим Python, так и использование системных вставок символов, к примеру, для открытия окна смайликов в Windows 10 используется сочетание клавиш `Win + :`.